# ngx-charts Step chart

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

Is it possible to implement a step chart using ngx-charts?

https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/

[Step chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K563E.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box? I don't think so. Simplest way is data multiplication I guess.

[image]

```json
export var multi = [
  {
    name: 'USA',
    series: [
      {
        name: '1990',
        value: 250000000,
      },
      {
        name: '2010',
        value: 250000000,
      },
      {
        name: '2010',
        value: 25000000,
      },
      {
        name: '2011',
        value: 25000000,
      },
      {
        name: '2011',
        value: 88000000,
      },
      {
        name: '2012',
        value: 88000000,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-line-chart-bl4wjq?file=app%2Fdata.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which line interpolation is used in your line chart by using the curve property: https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/line-area-charts/line-chart

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart [results]="data"
                       [curve]="curve">
```

According to the documentation any [d3 curve function](https://d3js.org/d3-shape) can be used. Example for a line chart with "step before":

```
import * as shape from "d3-shape";

public curve = shape.curveStepBefore;
```

For interpolation examples see here: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/line-chart

[ngx-charts-line-chart with stepBefore line interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgYUy.png)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I switched to Angluar wrapper for Apache Echarts. They have step chart out of the box.

https://xieziyu.github.io/ngx-echarts/#/welcome